# ArgumentException: Unrecognized property 'user id' in connection string

Tags: .net, connection-string, advantage-database-server

I'm using:

- Advantage Database Server 10
- Advantage.Data.Provider.dll (v.9.10.2.9)

Everything works pretty stable on most of workstations, but today one of our new customers had reported that he experiencing troubles with our app. The logs shows the following strage exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Unrecognized property 'user id' in
>   connection string.    at
>   Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsConnectionStringHandler.ParseConnectionString(String
>   strConnect)    at
>   Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsPoolManager.GetConnection(String
>   strConnectionString, AdsInternalConnection& internalConnection,
>   AdsConnectionPool& pool)    at
>   Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsConnection.Open()

As soon as the same code works well by all other customers, I guess the problem could be related to the running environment, but I'm still trying to figure out what exactly can cause this problem.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I just looked through the `Advantage.Data.Provider.dll` code and found that they are using a `Hashtable` to match the connection string properties and `Hashtable`'s initialization looks a little strange for me:

```
public static Hashtable CreateCaseInsensitiveHashtable()
{
  return new Hashtable((IEqualityComparer) StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

I guess `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` could be a trouble here, but I need to check.

Comment: can you post the connection string? (can be without usernames/passwords just so we can see the format)

Comment: @FedorHajdu the connection string is quite normal, it looks like: `data source=\\server\db\system-1\maindb.add;servertype=Remote;user id=admin;password=***;TrimTrailingSpaces=true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in versions 9.10.0.21 and later of the client.  From the [page with the download link](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=13&Product=4&Platform=11):

> 2 - Fixed a bug in the Advantage .NET Data Provider that caused connection strings not to be parsed correctly for some locales (tr-TR specifically).

Comment: Oh, that is great, thanks! I thought I have the latest 9.* version.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, year, `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` was the issue. It looks like the bug in the `Advantage.Data.Provider.dll`. The `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` should be used instead. The following code shows the issue:

```
foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    var isEquals = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
                                 .Compare("user id", "User ID") == 0;

    if (!isEquals)
        Console.WriteLine("culture: {0}; equals: {1}", culture.Name, isEquals);
}
```

it gives an output:

```
culture: tr; equals: False
culture: az; equals: False
culture: tr-TR; equals: False
culture: az-Latn-AZ; equals: False
culture: az-Latn; equals: False
```

The workaround should be simple - use `User ID` in the connection string. I will ask a customer which culture is currently set in the system.

**UPDATE**

The customer confirmed that he has the Turkish culture.